# How do you create and modify a boolean state provider in riverpod for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm trying to create a global provider that will hold a boolean value as part of a provider family

```
final PaginationProvider = StateProvider.family((ref, id) => true);
```

But my attempts to set the value as I would with other providers is a fail

```
context.read(PaginationProvider(0)).state = false;
```

The specific error is

```
Unhandled Exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This UncontrolledProviderScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  UncontrolledProviderScope
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  Builder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't even know why but this fixed the problem.

Leaving it here incase someone else has this issue

```
    Future.delayed(
        Duration.zero,
            () => context
            .read(PaginationProvider(0))
            .state = false);
```

Comment: The reason this works is that it delays the state change by a single frame, allowing the initial build to occur before changing the state (which also causes a build). Without delaying that single frame, you end up in an infinite loop of rebuilding.

Comment: @AlexHartford Is this an improper 'hack' of a fix to my issue?

Comment: No, it's fine. I think `WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback` would make it more obvious what you're doing but accomplishes the same thing.